# Array filter not working for state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array which is a state, The values of the state show in a view, I also have a text view, I want to make the value of the text input change the values of the state so that the values in the state view will change, but it doesn't change the values in the state view,
i.e if i type `a`, the view doesn't change, if i type `ab` it comes back with an error saying `undefined is not an object(evaluating item.toLowerCase)`
Please where may I may be wrong

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schools: [
        "Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University, Bauchi",
        "Ahmadu Bello University, Zaria",
        "Bayero University, Kano",
      ],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.schoolChange = this.schoolChange.bind(this);
  }

  schoolChange(text) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.schools.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.schools[i]);
    }
    let c = this.state.schools.map(item => item.toLowerCase(item));
    let b = c.filter(item => item.indexOf(text) > -1);
    let d = b.map(item => item.toUpperCase(item));
    console.log(d);
    var len = d.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      let row = d[i];
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          schools: [...prevState.schools, row],
        }),
        console.log(this.state.schools[i]),
      );
    }
  }

  handleChange(text) {
    this.setState({ text }, () => {
      this.schoolChange(this.state.text);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const schools = this.state.schools.map((school, index) => (
      <Text style={styles.text}>{school}</Text>
    ));

    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Search"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={text => this.handleChange(text)}
        />
        <ScrollView overScrollMode={"never"} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
          {schools}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are overriding schools array and now there is no data to filter on. Your source of data is `this.state.schools` and on filter, you are replacing schools array with new data, maybe empty array so now you don't have a way to get your data back to filter. So instead of keping your source data in state, keep it in some global variables or in `this.schools` so updating state will not change the source

Keep a copy of data. YOu don't need to setState in loop. SImply calculate data and then setState.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.schools = [
                   "Abubakar Tafawa Balewa University, Bauchi",
                   "Ahmadu Bello University, Zaria",
                   "Bayero University, Kano"
                ];
        this.state = {
                schools: this.schools
        }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
  
 handleChange(text){
     const schools = this.schools.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1);
     this.setState({ schools });
 }
```

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean when you say I am overriding schools array

Comment: @AdokiyeIruene Updated my answer, I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

You could also simplify your *schoolChange* function:

```
schoolChange(text){
     const schools = this.schools.filter(school => school.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase()));
     this.setState({
       schools,
     });
 }
```

Comment: this.schools in undefined

Comment: I was referring to your answer, where you set it in the constructor. I've just noticed that you did almost the same thing in your answer, just not in schoolChange but in handleChange function.